# Want to resize shapes(Rectangle) by cursor using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I successfully drawn the rectangle by mouse but fail to resize that.
I've tried multiple ways using event  by calling function but fail.

New to python so struggling.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the resize on callbacks bound on `self.canvas`, don't need to bind on the rectangle item.

Below is an simplified example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=512, height=512, cursor="cross")
        self.canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
        self.canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_button_press)
        self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        # find rectangle items under mouse cursor
        items = [x for x in self.canvas.find_withtag("current") if self.canvas.type(x) == "rectangle"]
        if items:
            # item found, use it as the "current" item
            self.start = self.canvas.coords(items[0])[:2]
            self.current = items[0]
        else:
            # no item found, create new "current" rectangle item
            self.start = event.x, event.y
            self.current = self.canvas.create_rectangle(*self.start, *self.start, width=5)

    def on_move_press(self, event):
        # resize the "current" item
        self.canvas.coords(self.current, *self.start, event.x, event.y)

ExampleApp().mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi,
I tried this by customizing your code by opening image and then drawing the shape on image but condition below

items = self.canvas.find_withtag("current")

Tuple storing value (1,) after opening image and this causing  code execution to move inside the if condition and then exception raised.

My problem statement is : need to open image and mark the rectangle. Those rectangle should be drawn by mouse and they can be delete or resize or moved to anywhere on image.

Comment: @KratikaVarshney Answer updated to find rectangle items under mouse cursor inside `on_button_press()` function.

Answer (score 0):

few errors `self.current = self.create_rectangle(*self.start, *self.start, width=5)` should be `self.canvas.create_rectangle(*self.start, *self.start, width=5)`

similarly `self.tag_bind` should be `self.canvas.tag_bind`

remove `self.canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_click)` and `self.__init__(filename)` from `openFile` method

Also, don't forget to import partial (`from functools import partial`)